# Why Isodecane (B.P.: 327 *C) has a higher boiling point than decane (B.P.: 174.1 *C)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

Branched chain molecules have lower boiling point than straight chain molecules because branched chain molecules have a smaller surface area where they can be attracted by other molecules. Then, why Isodecane (a branched chain molecule) has a higher boiling point than Decane (a straight chain molecule)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean 2-methylnonane with isodecane, your data is wrong.

2-methylnonane has a boiling point around 166 °C, which would support the rule of thumb that you mentioned.

Comment: :I am grateful to you. Actually this was the boiling point of isodecane given in my textbook. Now, I have come to know that the given information is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The only problem here is the units - the boiling point of isodecane is given in Fahrenheit and the boiling point of decane in Celsius.

Comment: Your answer has been flagged as low quality, which was disputed, but nevertheless you might want to expand your future answers a little more in order to avoid this. [answer] gives a short, helpful introduction.